# Change input Value by another input before post

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I have this a simple form but the "Value" for engine make needs to be different depending on the location selected! let's say if I select Austraia the Value for engine make should be 1 but if America the value should be 6.

I need javascript that can change the value depending on the location, basically each engine make will need two values!

```
     <input type="radio" id="enginemake1" name="enginemake" value="6" checked/><label for="enginemake1">Chevrolet</label><br>

     <input type="radio" id="enginemake3" name="enginemake" value="7"/><label for="enginemake3">Ford</label><br>


     <input type="radio" id="location1" name="location" value="us" checked/><label for="location1">America</label><br>
     <input type="radio" id="location2" name="location" value="au"/><label for="location2">Australia</label><br>
```

Comment: What js have you tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$("#location1").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#enginemake1").val(1);
    }
})
$("#location2").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#enginemake1").val(6);
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the code on your "head" tag:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#yourButton").on("click", function () {
            $("input[name='location']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val()=="au") {

                    $("input[name='enginemake']").removeAttr("checked");
                    $("#enginemake3").attr("checked", "checked");
                }
                if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "us") {

                    $("input[name='enginemake']").removeAttr("checked");
                    $("#enginemake1").attr("checked", "checked");
                }

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```